# Is there a way to have four possible outcomes without repeating the two conditions?

Tags: coding-style, code-quality, clean-code, source-code, programming-logic

In a generic sense, my question goes something like this:

```cs
if (p) {
    if (q) {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
} else {
    if (q) {
        c();
    } else {
        d();
    }
}
```

There are four outcomes `a()`, `b()`, `c()`, and `d()` depending on the conditions `p` and `q`. Even though `p` and `q` will only be evaluated once in any case, `q` is still repeated in the code. I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid this redundancy.

In my specific case, I'm in a situation where one outcome is actually nothing happening, and another outcome is an additional thing happening. So it looks like this:

```cs
if (p) {
    a();
    if (q) {
        b();
    }
} else {
    if (q) {
        c();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to write this out so that `p` and `q` each only show up once? I'm usually good at rearranging things to avoid redundancy but I don't know if it's possible in this case. If it's not possible then is there some recommended way to phrase logical structure like this?

Here I'm using C# but I'll accept answers in any language.

EDIT: My question is certainly similar to [How to turn truth table into smallest possible if / else block](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102757/how-to-turn-truth-table-into-smallest-possible-if-else-block) and I find its answers helpful, but my question looks to me to differ in the sense that I'm specifically asking how to avoid the redundant condition.

Comment: Yes it's possible in languages supporting function pointers or lambda functions.  However, the result will not be as fast as what an optimizing compiler can generate.

Comment: @gnat it's more complex than a truth table, because the `a()`
 function could change the value of `q` under some circumstances.

Comment: @Christophe Good point about changing the value of `q`, but that doesn't happen in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, it's do-able, and may be a good idea**

Certainly this is doable, and it can often yield clearer logic, depending on what parameters you are using. Hopefully the parameters are related in some way that ties into a well-understood business concept.

**Identify the hidden business concept**

In cases where the two parameters map to a single (hidden) business concept, you need to make that concept explicit, using a mapping function that takes `p` and `q` and outputs the case.

This example corresponds to your first example:

```
z = map(p, q)
switch (z)
    case z1:
       a();
       break;
    case z2:
       b();
       break;
    case z3:
       c();
       break;
    case z4:
       d();
       break;
}
```

Or for your second example:

```
z = map(p, q)
switch (z)
    case z1:
       a();
       break;
    case z2:
       a();
       b();
       break;
    case z3:
       c();
       break;
    case z4:
       //No operation
       break;
}
```

**What is the mapping function?**

The mapping function can be as simple as combining `p` and `q` into a bitmask (if they are Booleans) or combining strings (if they are, for example, product and subproduct codes). This could be a stretch in some circumstances, but is a plain and obvious solution in other circumstances. For example, consider these questions that may appear on an application for health insurance:

1. Are you married?  Yes or no
2. Do you have children? Yes or no

In this case, your company might offer four products (the hidden business concept): single, married, single with children, and married with children. In this sort of scenario it is perfectly justified to combine the user's answers into a virtual product (given by the mapping function) and choosing a logic path based on the product instead of the individual flags. In fact it is much better code, IMO.

**Getting rid of the switch case**

Switch/case is ugly. Another approach would continue to use the hidden business concept but in a cleaner code pattern:

```
IProduct z = ProductFactory.GetProduct(q, p);
z.Execute();
```

...where the factory could return one of four products, all of which implement `IProduct` which contains a product-specific `Execute` method that will execute `a()`, `b()`, `c()`, and/or `d()` as needed.

**Won't the factory have the same (original) issue?**

The factory could contain nested `if` statements (bringing back the original problem) or it could use a lookup table for instantiation, like this:

```
class ProductFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<bool, Dictionary<bool, Func<IProduct>>> _products  
                      = new Dictionary<bool, Dictionary<bool, Func<IProduct>>>();

    static ProductFactory()
    {
        _products.Add(false, new Dictionary<bool, Func<IProduct>> {
            { true,  () => new ProductSingleWithChildren() },
            { false, () => new ProductSingle() }
        });
        _products.Add(true, new Dictionary<bool, Func<IProduct>> {
            { true,  () => new ProductMarriedWithChildren() },
            { false, () => new ProductMarried() }
        });

     }
    public IProduct GetProduct(bool isMarried, bool hasChildren)
    {
        return _products[isMarried][hasChildren]();
    }
}
```

...where `_products` is a list of lists, each item containing a `Func<IProduct>` that will instantiate the appropriate type.

Dictionaries with a key of `bool` seem a little weird, so in an actual piece of code you might lean toward using an `enum` instead, or possible a `string` containing a code. I would suggest using an identifier that is aligned with the business/domain; make it easy for other developers to understand what is going on.

For completeness, here is an idea what the classes would look like:

```
interface IProduct
{
    void Execute();
}
class ProductSingle : IProduct
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        a();
    }
}
class ProductSingleWithChildren : IProduct 
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        a();
        b();
    }
}
class ProductMarried: IProduct 
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        c();
    }
}
class ProductMarriedWithChildren : IProduct 
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        //No operation
    }
}
```

You'll notice in the end we not only got rid of the duplicate `if` condition, there are in fact ZERO `if` statements in the whole solution!!! :) Pretty neat, and will get you a low cyclomatic complexity score and a nice clean CPU pipeline. Plus much more readable code.

Then again, we just wrote a LOT more lines of code than the original example. So, depending on context, maybe the nested `if` statements would be better, in certain cases, e.g. the combination of the flags is arbitrary or doesn't map to a logical concept within the business problem, or the extra readability isn't necessary for a certain small problem. It's up to you, of course.

Comment: Might be nice to show the enum containing the bits.

Comment: Nice answer for the general case! But for the OP's specific case, this supposes that a() has no side effect on q. And trades 2 show ups of q in the original source code against to show ups of a() in your proposal (being understood that in both cases the execution path will only make use of one, and for the OP it seems to be only a matter of avoiding duplication in the source code).

Answer (score 3):

### Short philosophical answer

It is tempting to present a nice trick.  I will later in the answer.  But I'd prefer to first address the root cause of your problem, even if you might not like it:

> I'm usually good at rearranging things to avoid redundancy
>    - Kyle Delaney

Yes, certainly. But are you as good as your optimizing compiler? Let this kind of low level rearranging to your compiler and focus on the correct code.  The compiler has much more trick, as it can work on assembler level.

> Premature optimisation is the root of all evil 
>   - [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)
>
> Don't diddle code to make it faster; find a better algorithm. 
>   [- B.W.Kernighan & P.J.Plauger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style)

### Long answer: Yes it's possible but not necessarily better

I'll write in C++ as you accept solutions in any language.

Your initial code with 10 instructions will generate different code depending on how you initialize `p` and `q`, and what the compiler knows about `a()`, `b()` and `c()`

Here the assembly result if `p` and `q` are initialized with a random number.  The compiler will keep them in registers as long as possible:

```
    call    rand         ;  p is returned in register eax
    mov     ebx, eax     ;  ultrafast move to another register
    call    rand         ;  so that q can be kept in register eax
    test    ebx, ebx     ;  check if p is null 
    jne     .L11         ;  if not null continue at .L11 to call a() etc...
    test    eax, eax     ;  here we're in the "else": check if q is null 
    jne     .L12         ;  if not null go to .L12 to call c() and finish
.L4:
    ...                  ; function exit code, not relevant for us
    ret 
.L12:
    call    c()
    jmp     .L4
.L11:
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], eax   ; save q : register might be overwritten
    call    a()                       ; execute a() 
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]   ; restore q
    test    eax, eax                  ; and test if it's null
    je      .L4                       
    call    b()                       ; if it's not call b(). 
    jmp     .L4
```

As you see, there are two accesses to `q` as in the source code.  No way round this, apparently.  However, the code is mostly register based so very fast.

Now a variant, where `p` and `q` are initialized from the standard input.  To do this, the address of `p` and `q` must be "leaked" to a library function, and once leaked, as the compiler doesn't know what happens in `a()`, `b()` and `c()`, it assumes the worst (i.e., that each of this function could maliciously modify the booleans reusing the "leaked" address).

Long story short, it'll be [17 relevant assembly instructions](https://godbolt.org/g/1E5izo).  Again, `q` will be read in two instructions.  Unfortunately here `p` and `q` will be written and read from the stack memory, because of the above mentioned constraint.  Memory access is slightly slower than register access.  So this version will be less performant.  But you see, the compiler takes a lot of things into consideration. WOuld you have thought about the risk of `q` being changed by `a()` ?

Finally, I propose a **solution** using a function pointer. It can probably be implemented in a similar manner in other languages that support lambda functions.

```
void (*x)() = c;   // function pointer pointing by default to c() function
if (p) {          // if it's p then we will execute a()
    a();
    x = b;        // and depending on q, we could have to execute b() later instead of c()
}
if (q) {
    x();          // call the function pointed to
}
```

I'm not sure that it will add to the readability of the code,  but `p` and `q` are accessed only in one place. The code is also shorter: 6 instructions in the source code and [14 relevant instructions in the assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/Le8CMU).  I could feel satisfied, but is it really a good idea ?

Unfortunately, the call to the function pointer will be slower than a direct call to the function address (because of the indirection). And the CPU will have to execute one or two additional statements to load and update the function pointer.  So despite being of shorter size and nicely arranged, it will result in slower and less readable code.

Therefore, I'd strongly reiterate my first philosophical answer.

Comment: Wh do you think that rearrangement is for optimizing the running code instead of minimizing the source? All else being equal, shorter code is easier to comprehend because there's less of it.

Comment: @Deduplicator I can't agree with shorter code being easier to comprehend.  I've edited my answer to propose a C++ solution (OP accepts any language) using function pointers,  but it could be implemented in any language that supports lambda functions. The source is shorter, but the generated code will be slower, and the human mind will have to think twice to follow a logic that was very natural in OP's initial code.  ;-)

Comment: Well, "all else being equal". Naturally, that condition does not always apply.

Comment: "Don't diddle code to make it faster; find a better algorithm." This quote makes no sense to me. For one thing, I'm already trying to find a better algorithm. Also, where is the line drawn between diddling code to make it faster and finding a better algorithm? There doesn't seem to be a clear distinction.

Comment: @KyleDelaney didling code is to change for find small optimisations in order to gain to gain a couple of ms here and there but without changing fundamentally the approach. Finding a better algorithm consist of using a different approach to solve the problem. I agree that your approach is somewhat btw the two,  I can remove this quote if it upsets you.

Comment: @Christophe.  Nice solution using function pointers.

Comment: @Christophe Your answer is actually very good. I'd surely pick it as my second choice. I like your concise code example based on my specific situation. And it would work in other languages using delegates or function variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Simply concatenate P and Q and put the result into your conditional.

The question is why would you do this?

Comment: To avoid redundancy (`if (q)` showing up multiple times).

Comment: its not redundant.

Comment: What do you think redundant means?

Comment: unneeded. in this case you need it, ether expressly, or hidden by some maths. You cant get around it. Theres no alternate algorithm. The only question is how you want to express it and why you would think hiding the expression in a function is better than expressing it with if  statements

Comment: Your argument for why it's not redundant is because there's no way around it. But my question was to determine if there is a way around it. You're saying I shouldn't want a solution simply because there is no solution.

Comment: no. Theres more than one way to express the condition. I'm asking what is it that makes you value one over the other. Concatenation meets your criteria of not using the same condition twice. but its not more performant or less lines of code or easier to understand.